# Securely storing sensitive information in a standalone Java application

Tags: java, encryption

I am working on a standalone Java application and I need to securely store sensitive information such as passwords and API keys without using a cloud management system. At present it is hardcoded in the code as mentioned below. How can retrieve it during runtime? What are the best practices for securely storing and managing the key?

```
public static final String TECH_USER_TOKEN = "SomePassword";
```

## Update

I discovered a cloud solution that allows me to securely store sensitive information. The system provides a URL with a token to access the information in JSON format. The question is, where should the token be placed to access the cloud URL without hardcoding it? This is a requirement for a standalone application.

Comment: Let the user enter a password at startup and use that password for deriving a (symmetric) encryption key?

Comment: If you are trying to secure the information from access by the user on hardware controlled by the user, then what you are trying to do is not possible.  Either way, your question is missing important information.

Comment: @StephenC I have updated the question, could you please take a look ?

Comment: You now have exactly the same problem as if you embedded the sensitive information in your app.  But, now the sensitive information is the token for retrieving the original sensitive information.  You haven't achieved anything.  See the first sentence of my previous comment.  Note "... it is not possible."   Whether or not it is a requirement.

Comment: I think you need to be more cautious about taking on programming work that has impossible requirements.  It won't end well ....

Answer (score 0):

Used

> Jasypt

encryption library and solved the problem.
Thanks every one for support!